# How to display entries in a table?

Tags: channel-entries

Suppose I have a 3 column table and 9 channel entries A to I. I'd like to display the entries in the three columns in three rows:

row 1: A D G

row 2: B E H

row 3: C F I

I see a channel {count} variable which will give me the number of entries selected from the channel.

I'm using css and div tags to display data in a table format.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you want to do is to transpose the table (so rows appear as columns).

There are ways you could do this within EE, but they would require knowing for sure the likely structure of the table that you plan to transpose.

However an easier solution might be to restructure the table in the browser.  There are a few solutions - here is one from [elsewhere within stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918094/html-table-with-vertical-rows#16919439) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918094/html-table-with-vertical-rows#16919439

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use flexbox (css) flex-direction:column.  I will try to make you a example soon..  do you want a limited number of entries in each columns? Same height on columns?

Take a look a this codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pabxdg